URL gets appended with /test/ twice when using Inertia.js with Laravel
I'm experiencing an issue with Laravel and Inertia.js where the URL is being appended with /test/ twice when rendering a page. My project is hosted at https://something.com/test/, but when attempting to view the login/register page, the URL changes to https://something.com/test/test/login, which causes redirection issues and 404 errors.
Here’s the relevant code:

Laravel Route and Controller:

// routes/web.php
Route::get('/login', [AuthenticatedSessionController::class, 'create'])->name('login');

// app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthenticatedSessionController.php
public function create(): Response
{

// if I place dd('something'); here, the url is okay, it doesn't add another /test/, so I think problem will be with Inertia render

    return Inertia::render('Auth/Login', [
        'canResetPassword' => Route::has('password.request'),
        'status' => session('status'),
    ]);
}


App.js Configuration:

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, App, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(App, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue)
            .mount(el);
    },
    progress: {
        color: '#126afb',
    },
});


.env Configuration:

APP_URL=https://something.com/test
ASSET_URL=https://something.com/test


.htaccess Configuration:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /test/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening or how to fix it?
tried configuring the Laravel Inertia.js and Vue components for rendering the login page without appending extra segments to the URL. Specifically, I:
Checked and adjusted the Inertia.js setup to ensure correct routing.

Verified the Vue component configuration to ensure no URL manipulation was occurring within the client-side code.
Examined the .env and .htaccess configurations for potential URL base path issues.
I expected the URL to remain consistent at https://something.com/test/login when rendering the login page.

However, the actual result was that the URL incorrectly changed to https://something.com/test/test/login, leading to a redirection issue and resulting in a 404 error when refreshing the page.
Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening or how to fix it?
Thank you in advance!

In the network tab, are the Vue resources correctly loaded from '/test/resources/js/..'? Does your page contain a 'base href'?

as default you are putting your .htaccess file in your domain root directory and the .htaccess file you are providiing has a RewriteRule  of handling all your requests by the /test/index.php file and its known for laravel to place the index.php file /public/index.php so if you can provide the fullpath of your index.php file so I can provide you with the right RewriteRule ?
